# How to prevent publishers from creating Featured Articles in Joomla 1.6?

Tags: php, joomla, permissions, acl

How can I prevent users who have the Publishers permission from creating Featured Articles in Joomla 1.6? Will I need to write PHP/JavaScript code to do so, or is there a way to do this in Joomla's admin pages?

Comment: Since there was an answer to this question that helped you, please consider marking it as Accepted (the check-mark next to the answer) so that other people will know how you solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS-only solution that Brent's answer proposes has a flaw: if the Publisher user has the Firebug extension, Web Inspector, or a similar functionality running, they can just remove the `display:none;` style from the field.

The solution I am using in my own project, and would recommend to you, is to use a template override. Overriding `/com_content/form/edit.php` will let you totally remove that option from the display.

Answer (score 1):

That function is not built in, but there is an easy way to handle it if you are talking about front end editing. All you need to do is add this to your template stylesheet -

```
#jform_featured-lbl,#jform_featured {
  display:none
}
```

The field will still be there as far as the form is concerned and the default value is No. You could also do a template override and remove the field completely from the form (or change it to a hidden field with a value of No) if you are familiar with template overrides.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to prevent them from creating any articles

1. Login to joomla backend
2. Goto The Article Manager
3. Click the icon with the word Options
   under it on the toolbar
4. Click "Permissions" tab
5. Click Publisher
6. Set the "Create" action to "Denied"
7. Click "Save & Close"

If you are only wanting the publishers to create only in certain sections

1. Login to joomla backend
2. Goto The Categories Manager
3. Edit each Category you dont want
   them creating articles in
4. At the bottom of the edit page set
   the Publisher's Permissions for
   Create to Denied
5. Save

Comment: He wants publisher to not have the option to make an article featured. That can't be done within the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Featuring is part of edit.state I believe so you can do a few things.  I'm assuming you want them to have the other edit state features, correct? So what you want to do is to make a plugin that creates a new permission called featuring and then wrap a check for that permission around the feature field in a layout override. Or you can unset featured for that group.  You can create a permission using an XML string in your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:
in the index.php template, just before `</head>` tag:

```
<?php
//este script tiene como objetivo que el desplegable "destacado" solamente aparezca     
//cuando el usuario es admin
$usuario = JFactory::getUser();
$joomla_usuario = $usuario->username;
if ($joomla_usuario!="admin")
{
echo '<style type="text/css">#formelm,#jform_featured-lbl,#jform_featured {
  display:none;}</style>';
}
?>
```